# Creating a link like those in Getting Started WebPart

Tags: web-part, picture

So I want to make a hyperlink with a picture and description that shows on mouse hover but using a particular user profile picture (like HR department director, admin or any other director from other department). And that link have actually be a link to the department where the person is from.

If I get it right I have to create a list containing the URL, the picture, the description, the title and so on. But I don't want this list to be visible to everyone they would only be able to see the webpart.

But what is the webpart I have to use to make something like this. It should look like in the "Geting Started" wePart Something like this: https://officeblogseast.blob.core.windows.net/wp-content/migrated-images/PublishingImages/12-14-12/image-3.png

And I guess I just need to configure the list that it has to use in webpart edit menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use "Promoted links" list to get look like "Getting Started" webpart

1. From the home page of your SharePoint site on the Quick Launch click Site Contents.
2. On the Site Contents page under Lists, Libraries, and other Apps click add an app.
   [image]
3. On the Your Apps page scroll down and click Promoted Links
   [image]

For reference: [How to create promoted links](http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-promoted-links-list-app-part-1)